# How to debug a hanging unit test run session in VS2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resharper, nunit-3.0, vstest

I have a project with a huge number of unit test cases (around 40000!)

They run successfully locally and on my TeamCity server within nunit2 framework. Recently I migrated to nunit3. Since then I observe that if I run them one by one they run ok. But if I run all of them as a session they hang (get stuck at random test cases). The test cases the session hangs at, run ok when individually executed. But again if I run the session of 40000 tets cases it would hang at some new random test case subsequently. The hanging behavior is not consistent.

I tried using Visual Studio test explorer, Resharper test case session UI, nunit3.console.exe,  vstest.console.exe tools to execute test cases. All exhibit hanging behavior more or less similar manner. Just one observation that nunit3-console.exe can reach 28500 test cases before hanging. vstest however hangs at 5000 test cases. The Resharper test case plugin also hangs around the same number.

It is because of this on my CI/CD TeamCity server also, every attempt to run the entire session of 40000 test cases hangs and times out on similar fashion. I don't use any timeout attribute and have undergone typical unit3 migration changes as suggested in the nunit3 docs (summary link https://davembush.github.io/nunit-2-vs-nunit-3-what-you-need-to-know/).

How can I diagnose what could be the issue when I can guess it doesn't look like a fault of any specific test case?

Comment: Out of interest, how big is your code base to warrant 40,000 unit tests? Do you get 100% code coverage with that many tests? Could they be broken up in to smaller chunks and run separately? I assume the unit test runners are 32 bit and maybe running out of memory/resources, have you monitored these?